# "Read more" link doesn't show up when the post length is under the excerpt length

Tags: excerpt, read-more

I have posts with very different post lengths.

Sometimes there are very long posts, sometimes a very short comment on a book.

I have set my excerpt length to 50 words, but when a post is 25 words long, the "Read more" link doesn't show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a same issue and solved it by changing code in the content.php (the template for the content). The code started with `echo wp_trim_words( get_the_excerpt(),50,` and I changed it by just using `echo get_the_excerpt(),` no trim no number ... to set a max amount words you then can use a function and your problem should be solved.(Or just except WP basic setting max. 55 words and you also do without an extra function)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the [following check](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L2676-L2682) in the `wp_trim_words()` function:

```
if ( count( $words_array ) > $num_words ) {
    array_pop( $words_array );
    $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
    $text = $text . $more;
} else {
    $text = implode( $sep, $words_array );
}
```

You can therefore try the following:

```
add_filter( 'wp_trim_words', function( $text, $num_words, $more ) {
    return $more === mb_substr( $text, -1 * mb_strlen( $more ) ) ? $text : $text . $more;
}, 11, 3 );
```

to append the `$more` link to the `$text`, if it's missing.

But I think your readers might be disappointent when they click the link on short posts and discover there's nothing new to read ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Post Teaser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-teaser/) plugin on my site. Just install and set how many words you want to show on the page; a link underneath opens the full post.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by:

- disabling the readmore link

  ```
  add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
  function modify_read_more_link() {
    return '';
  }
  ```
- adding the link in the template

```
echo '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Read more...';
```