# Excerpt "Read More" link

Tags: excerpt

In my [blog](http://www.seoundesem.com/blog) I want to put a label "Read More" and after clicking it, I want all my posts to appear but it's not working. Here is my code to try to be more specific:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','openstrap_excerpt');
function openstrap_excerpt(){
    global $post;
    $link='<span class="readmore"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" > Continue reading &rarr;</a></span>';
    $excerpt=get_the_excerpt();     
    if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post->post_content) ) { 
        echo $excerpt.$link;
    } else {
        echo $excerpt;
    }
}
function openstrap_excerpt_read_more($text) {
   return '  <span><a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="readmore">Continue reading &rarr;</a></span>';

}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'openstrap_excerpt_read_more');

function openstrap_custom_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 85;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'openstrap_custom_excerpt_length');
```

Comment: why are you using this if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post->post_content) ) {

Comment: I wonder if you want to display the "Read more" link, regardless of the post length? Then [this recent question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/194439/26350) is related.

Answer (score 0):

i think this may solve your problem by removing this condition  `if ( preg_match('/<!--more(.*?)?-->/', $post->post_content) ) {`

Not sure but give it a try

Adds Read More after the excerpt.

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','openstrap_excerpt');
function openstrap_excerpt(){
    global $post;
    $link='<span class="readmore"><a href="'.get_permalink().'" > read more &rarr;</a></span>';
    $excerpt=get_the_excerpt();   
    echo $excerpt.$link;

}
```

Following code Limit the length of the excerpt to 20 words

```
function openstrap_custom_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 85;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'openstrap_custom_excerpt_length');
```

I don't why you are using the third function/filter and perhaps not required

Comment: dont happen nothing . please check [www.seoundsem.com/blog]

Comment: you want read more instead of continur reading ,, right?

Comment: just use the code i just edited . Don't use other two functions

Comment: i want to continue reading  after first 20 words and only appear one time,now there are 2 times continue reading

Comment: and also i want that when i upload a post appear in colums or something....not all together

Comment: like this http://seoundsem.com/reasons-why-companies-dont-invest-in-digital-marketing/ but cut with one continue reading

Comment: can you paste the code for blog page, coz it appearing two times is not issue of above code , its some thing different issue

Comment: problem solved! was something in cache memory i think

Comment: did my answer helped you?